# How can you modify the odds of winning at a wheel spin?

Tags: probability

So lets say you have a wheel divided in x sector
[image]

You want to rig the wheel to decrease the chances of someone landing on the green circle.
Now lets say you do it by putting magnets in the red object between each sector.
The magnets each have a value ranging between 0 (no attraction) and 1 (normal attraction) and depending on their force they slow the wheel a little everytime one passes the blue metal bar.

For a number x of sector and given the force of the spin and the initial rotation of the wheel are random, is there a way to set the values of the magnets so that your odds of winning are lower ?